# What's the best way to hardwire my workbench/shop light?

Tags: electrical, wiring

So I purchased some Barina T5 Led light bulbs (from amazon) and I am wanting to hardwire one of them for my work bench. I currently have a 20A outlet on the workbench as well as a 15A circuit that I was planning on hooking a switch to for said light. I checked the light out and they come with a standard two prong plug as well as a tiny 6 inch adapter for hardwiring. The adapter has the standard hot, neutral and ground wires. I am relatively new to house electrical, but the wires are a really small gauge and are stranded. I am sure it is fine, and this is what most power cords are like, but is it fine to just hook these directly to 12 gauge wiring (my 20A and 15A circuit are both ran with 12 gauge)?

I was planning to mount the light fixture above the work bench (underside of my overhead cabinets). The wiring would go behind a pegboard/slat wall that I plan to put on the back wall. Since the wiring harness they provided is so short, I will have to splice it to a longer set of wires. What's the best way to go about this? I should probably have some sort of junction box where I splice right? Can I not just use some butt connectors to splice to romex/nm to the back wall? Maybe run it through more conduit to my box? Is there a way to just extend the harness and not worry about running it through conduit?

Thanks

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: If an electrical device comes from the manufacturer with smaller gauge wires, that is legal( if it has a UL or similar listing).  You cannot replace wires on a device with smaller gauge wires.  Any splices must be in an accessible(not behind wall) box.

Comment: Have to agree with crip659 on nationally recognized testing UL or other. 
Verification of the listing is important! The box can be surface mounted like your boxes in the pic requires accessibility.

Comment: Since I’m going to have pegboard basically mounted flush with the outlet box cover, is it fine to just run the wiring from the light to the box behind it or does it NEED to be in conduit? Like if I splice the included adapter and wires into an old appliance cord, couldn’t that cord be exposed? Do the splices NEED to be in a box or as long as they are accessible? Considering permanent connections, like soldering to an older power cord, does that still have to be in a box?

Comment: If you need to install a junction box to connect the fixture's hardwire adapter to additional new wiring, IMO you may as well put an outlet in said box and use the plug that came with the fixture.   And then, of course, you have to wonder why you 
 don't just plug it into the existing outlet.    This problem is why I haven't replaced all my old shop lights with these super cheap LED fixtures.  Annoying and ugly.

Answer (score 1):

### Hooking them to house wiring is fine

These are likely 18AWG wires, no larger or smaller than what typically is used for light fixture leads in North America.  As a result, off-the-shelf wirenuts should have no difficulty splicing these to the 12AWG wires of your circuit.  You'll want to put a short length of conduit up from the existing receptacle box to a single gang "handy" box, with 14AWG wires in the conduit, though, so that you don't have to play "extend the extension" games with your lighting wiring.